# How to know if tcp server is in listening state or not

Tags: c#, sockets

I am developing one tcp server application using tcp listener in Windows service using c#.

After starting my service it works fine and accepts new clients.  After some time when ever the new client is trying to connect to server it gives the following exception:

> connection failed, is the server running? No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

At that time the service is in running state only.

How can I verify the tcp server is in listening state or not?

Comment: Can you paste the code ?

Answer (score 1):

**netstat -ab**

This command will give you information about all active connections with name of the programs.

Another option is [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) from Mark Russinovich

Answer (score 1):

If your server is still running and hasn't close the listening socket, it is still in listening state. However if the platform is Windows and your server's backlog queue is full, a windows will refuse further connections. That means that your server is slow accepting new connections.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean programatically or not, but for the latter, you can try telnet: telnet host port

```
telnet yahoo.com 80
telnet localhost 3306
```

etc.

Comment: That will have the same problem the applcation is having. It can't distinguish between 'not listening' and 'backlog queue full', which will cause a Windows server to refuse connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the server is listening, and the server is Windows, you can simply use (e.g. 8888 is your listening port)

```
netstat -ano|findstr "8888"
```

Then you'll see the PID of your server instance.

In addition, if you want to check why the TCP connection attempt is fail, you could use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to capture all the TCP packets between server & client, then the reason will be quite clear.

E.g. if the server has reached the limitation of open socket number, you'll see a SIN from client to server, and how the server is responding.

Comment: All connection refusals look the same on the wire: a FIN segment. You cannot discern the cause by what's on the wire.